# Reading an env variable in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, environment-variables

I need to read a private key from an env variable in kubernetes. To try that my code works I'm reading it now from the resource folder so everytime I'm running my app locally it can be read from it. The thing is now I've deployed my app and created a secret with this private key in kubernetes.

I've also created a test endpoint to check that my env variable is in kubernetes:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity test() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(System.getenv());
    }
```

After checking that it has been set, I've written this code in order to read that private key, it the app is running locally, from the resource folder but if it's runnign on dev, it has to be read from that env variable.
The thing is that this is not working when deployed to PaaS but it is read when trying locally.
Here's the code to achieve that:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtKeyProviderConfig {

    private final static String PRIVATE_KEY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME = "PRIVATE_KEY";
    private final static String LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT_NAME = "local";
    private final static String TEST_ENVIRONMENT_NAME = "test";
    private final static String DEVELOPMENT_ENVIRONMENT_NAME = "development";

    private final static String LOCAL_PRIVATE_KEY_RESOURCE_PATH = "classpath:keys/private_key.pkcs8";

    private final ResourceUtil resourceUtil;
    private final Base64Util base64Util;
    private final Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public PrivateKey getPrivateKeyFromEnvironmentVariable() throws IOException {
        List<String> activeProfiles = Arrays.asList(environment.getActiveProfiles());
        boolean isLocalOrTestEnvironment = activeProfiles.contains(LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT_NAME) || activeProfiles.contains(DEVELOPMENT_ENVIRONMENT_NAME);

        //TODO It's not reading from the ENV in openshift, it was reading it from the private key uploaded in git
        String key = isLocalOrTestEnvironment ? resourceUtil.asString(LOCAL_PRIVATE_KEY_RESOURCE_PATH) : System.getenv(PRIVATE_KEY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME);
        return readKey(
                key,
                "PRIVATE",
                this::privateKeySpec,
                this::privateKeyGenerator
        );
    }

    private <T extends Key> T readKey(String keyString, String headerSpec, Function<String, EncodedKeySpec> keySpec, BiFunction<KeyFactory, EncodedKeySpec, T> keyGenerator) {
        try {
            //TODO you can check the headers and throw an exception here if you want

            keyString = keyString
                    .replace("-----BEGIN " + headerSpec + " KEY-----", "")
                    .replace("-----END " + headerSpec + " KEY-----", "")
                    .replaceAll("\\s+", "");

            return keyGenerator.apply(KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"), keySpec.apply(keyString));
        } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new JwtInitializationException(e);
        }
    }

    private EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec(String data) {
        return new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(base64Util.decode(data));
    }

    private PrivateKey privateKeyGenerator(KeyFactory kf, EncodedKeySpec spec) {
        try {
            return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
        } catch(InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new JwtInitializationException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Any idea why it's not working on remote?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you always read it from an env variable? Seems like that would let you get rid of all that complicated logic without loosing any significant functionality.

Comment: How do I set the this private final static String LOCAL_PRIVATE_KEY_RESOURCE_PATH = "classpath:keys/private_key.pkcs8" as an env variable locally?

Comment: Depends on your OS and shell, for example in bash: `export VARNAME="my value"`

Comment: @DiegoMG, please share some more info like if you are using docker, any app config on cloud etc? because this looks to me application is being deployed in cloud &  application.properties is not used for reading env variables

Comment: I'm using red hat openshift. It looks like when declaring the variable in that way, it will try to read it from the env variables which is not set locally but it is in the pods in openshift.

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated?

You can read environment variable with Spring like all configuration values with `@Value`

```
@Value("${PRIVATE_KEY}")
private String privateKey;
```

Comment: Where did you try that and what was the stacktrace?

Comment: If I try that I get-> Could not resolve placeholder 'PRIVATE_KEY' in value "${PRIVATE_KEY}"

Comment: This means that PRIVATE_KEY is not defined. Do you get this on K8S or local?

Comment: Locally it's reading it from the resource folder but that PRIVATE_KEY should be read on K8S

Comment: And where does it not work?